# TTS : avoid spellibg instead of word pronunciation?

Tags: text-to-speech, multilingual

Good day guys.
I am in a situation where people often write English words ( technical words ) while still writing thé main text in the native language.
In that case, TTS starts spelling the foreign word instead of pronunciating it.
When the spelled word is German it is suite annoying as words can be super lengthy.

I need to find a trick to either declare two or three possible langages right when launching TTS, or zccess some variable priorité to reading telling me that word is unknown ?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure. Try in TTS  ( French in main text) , using a few German words. German words are not fully pronouned but spelled instead, Here you go : 
En Suisse, nous aimons manger au petit dejeuner du rosti avec du weggli ou du eibrot

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind adding it as a code example so it’s more clear ? For instance are you using a `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` or something else?